# Symfony2.2 on shared hosting

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I've been working on a project using Symfony 2.2, and it's been going well up until the point I tried to upload it to a live site. Now I'm getting the PDO connection error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

My config file is as follows:

```
  imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~
    translator:      ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Account\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Sorry folks! Forgot about this!

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: convocloud
    database_user: root
    database_password: *****
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ************************
    database_path: null
```

I raised a ticket with the hosting company also, and they were pretty stumped. I don't usually post on here, it was pretty desperate! Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: Do you feel that this error is related to your code, rather than a credential or connectivity issue with the production database server? If so, will you explain why?

Comment: is your database configured properly on the shared host?

Comment: Confirm your database credentials first, using the (MySQL?) console in your server shell. "Connection refused" sounds like you need to open the firewall to allow the database connection to go out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a giddy goose indeed!

Make sure you run:

```
php app/console doctrine:ensure-production-settings --no-debug --env=prod
```

before deploying live! Sorry, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer, so it is marked as solved. This takes it out of the 'unanswered questions' lists too.

Comment: Not actually sure where you set a question as answered?

Comment: The green tick to the left of the question - you found it! `:)`